# What is the IntelliJ IDEA's Keymap's abbreviation feature useful for?

Tags: intellij-idea, keymapping

What is the "Abbreviation" feature in IntelliJ IDEA Keymap for? [Web help on Keymap](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/keymap.html) is silent about it.

[image: IntelliJ Keymap abbreviation screenshot]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

According to Andrey Dernov from JetBrains Support:

> You use abbreviation added in keymap for quick search an action when "Search everywhere" (double Shift).

After adding "foobar" abbreviation to Git annotation command.

[image]

I can find the abbreviation and invoke the command with double Shift.

[image]

Unfortunately, the functionality does not support partial entry.

[image]

I personally find Shift-⌘-A easier to use in that case, because the results are limited to commands only.

PS: JetBrains support rocks!

Update: There was a follow-up from JetBrains:

> The feature was recently added in IDEA, we haven't had time to update the documentation yet. We will do it in near future.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no luck invoking an abbreviation defined in a keymap using any of the "live template" shortcuts. Can you give me a concrete example on how to invoke a custom-defined keymap abbreviation? Say, a custom `annot` abbreviation defined on the `Main menu -> VCS -> Git -> Annotate` action.

Comment: @KonradJamrozik Actually, I'm having troubles invoking keymap abbreviations myself. I sent an email to IntelliJ support asking for clarification. I will update the answer once I get a reply from them.

Comment: @KonradJamrozik Updated the answer with info from JetBrains.

Comment: Thanks! I guess it might be helpful for very short abbreviations (max 3 letters) for actions that don't always show up as first option in `Find Action...` box. For example, when I search for `keymap` I get `Default keymap reference` instead of `Keymap`, so abbreviation like `km` would be useful.

Comment: +1 to the question and answer both. Very nice feature! It's like a poor man's command-mode.

Comment: I had added an abbreviation to a shortcut because I didn't know what that was for.  After I read this, I tried looking up the shortcut by abbreviation.  It couldn't be found.  Inspired by another comment here to use short abbreviations, I made a much shorter abbreviation, and it worked.  Apparently there is a limit to how long an abbreviation should be, but IntelliJ IDEA doesn't give an error when assigning an abbreviation that is "too long".  It just silently fails.